# JavaFX - How to print text from a TextField

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Currently learning JavaFX and its capabilities.

I used SceneBuilder to create a TextField and button. I want to print what the user typed in the TextField when the button is clicked.

Why does this not print the values that the user entered into the TextBox?

```
    public void generateButtonClicked() {

    TextField forehandWinner = new TextField();
    forehandWinner.getText();
    System.out.println(forehandWinner);
```

FXML Button Code:

```
 <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#generateButtonClicked" text="Generate Statistics" />
```

FXML TextField Code:

```
<TextField id="forehandWinner" fx:id="forehandWinner" alignment="CENTER" promptText="Forehand Winners">
```

Comment: and not create forehandWinner manually.

Answer (score 2):

1. In your class you must declare the FXML TextField Object like this:

@FXML
private TextField forehandWinner;

2. After that, you must create the method generateButtonClicked like this:

public void generateButtonClicked(ActionEvent event)

3. In the generateButtonClicked method do something like this:

   public void generateButtonClicked(ActionEvent event){
   System.out.println(forehandWinner.getText());
   }

Comment: You don't need the `ActionEvent` parameter in the handler method.